# Why does my mesh have different colours

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
guys why is my blender model in both white and grey? I'm a noob, and I tried to find problems with the textures and materials, but seemingly the problem isn't there. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: select_all in edit mode and hit Ctrl+N , to recalculate normals

Comment: Many new users are asking that question, maybe flipped normals should be more obvious in 3D view, better color indication or Backface Culling enabled by default?